# Python: Fast way of finding the mean of large 4D-arrays filled with mostly zeros

Tags: python, large-data

I have many large 4D arrays I would like to take the average of. These arrays are mostly filled with zeros (>99%), but each array has non-zero values in different locations. Each array also has a corresponding array that weights it for taking the average.

Taking the average of the arrays in a straightforward way (below) takes a long time to compute, and often results in a memory error for me.

```
>>> a, b, weights_a, weights_b = [np.zeros((150,150,150,150)) for i in range(4)]

>>> valInds_a = np.random.randint(0,a.size,7000)
>>> valInds_b = np.random.randint(0,b.size,7000)

>>> a.ravel()[valInds_a] = np.random.random(7000)
>>> weights_a.ravel()[valInds_a] = np.random.random(7000)
>>> b.ravel()[valInds_b] = np.random.random(7000)
>>> weights_b.ravel()[valInds_b] = np.random.random(7000)

>>> avg = np.average([a,b],0, weights = [weights_a,weights_b])
```

I am looking for a faster way to computer this mean. I am thinking there is probably a way, since most of the values are zeros. I looked into using sparse arrays, but they do no support arrays with more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: You may want to look at sparse matrices.

Comment: I get "ZeroDivisionError: Weights sum to zero, can't be normalized" when running your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to only take the average where either of `a` or `b` is non-zero, since we know that the average will be zero otherwise.

If you have access to `valInds_a` and `valInds_b` this could be done like:

```
valInds_both = np.union1d(valInds_a, valInds_b)
avg = np.zeros_like(a)
avg.ravel()[valInds_both] = np.average(
    [a.ravel()[valInds_both], b.ravel()[valInds_both]],
    axis=0,
    weights=[weights_a.ravel()[valInds_both], weights_b.ravel()[valInds_both]])
```

Comment: I ended up employing a method similar to this, works well.